# EEPROM converted to DRAM?

Tags: memory, eeprom, dram

Can we use a EEPROM cell for DRAM ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foOwFD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is an EEPROM cell. Can we use multiple cells of this type to create a DRAM?

Comment: I have a feeling you might not understand what a DRAM or EEPROM is. Are you really just asking if you can use an EEPROM as RAM? EEPROM has limited endurance but is non-volatile, while and DRAM has unlimited write endurance but is volatile. You cannot use one in place of the other because the whole point of EEPROM is that it is non-volatile and the whole point of RAM (any RAM, not just DRAM) is that it has unlimited write endurance.

Comment: Both are capable of storing a bit. As such there is the same functionality. But that is where it ends. Access time, programmability,  retention and almost everything else is different.

Comment: Well as far as I know they storage information in the state of MOS capacitor (5T DRAM).Why should they differ?

Comment: @JellyStrawberry Okay. So it sounds like your question was asked base on a somewhat false or incomplete premise. It sounds like what you really want to know is the difference between an EEPROM and DRAM cell when they both store the bit in a capacitor. You should edit your question. The answer is that the DRAM has a regular capacitor while EEPROM has a floating/isolated capacitor. That's why the DRAM cap dumps all its charge and loses the stored bit when power is lost (even when power is there it's dumping its charge and needs to be refreshed) while the EEPROM maintains the charge.

Comment: _"This is an EEPROM cell"_ - Where's the floating Gate? _"Can we use multiple cells of this type to create a DRAM?"_ - Where's the storage capacitor?

Comment: @JellyStrawberry I kind of feel sorry for pointing this out, but: You don't have a single positive-vote question, and that's because you're not really asking based on your real understanding, but always on assumptions you make based on an extremely shallow understanding (that's often even wrong), and then hope that we guess your initial understanding and work with that. *That is a bad way of asking things,* and you waste most of your potential to learn something here by doing that! **Instead**, try to find your own assumptions.Ignore them.Ask only based on things you know for sure,not vaguely.

Comment: @MarcusMüller . . very good and kind words to OP jelly. I hope they help.

Answer (score 3):

No. Besides the fact that what you have drawn there is neither an EEPROM nor a DRAM cell, DRAM and EEPROM function in completely different ways; EEPROM relies on charge stored in a floating gate (which can be put there or removed only by tunnelling current), while DRAM is just a (very tiny) capacitor connected to the data line by a FET which turns on or off to control which bits are being read or written. The floating gate in EEPROM is a part of the FET itself.